# CAS could not starting from cas-overlay-template

Tags: java, gradle, cas

I am trying to install apereo CAS 7 from cas-overlay-template on my localhost I already install jdk 17 and already follow instructions there and generating thekeystores and cert files but no file named cas.properites created and when I'm trying to run the project this errer thrown

```
> Task :run FAILED
Error: Could not find or load main class Files\dotnet\;C:\Program
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Files\dotnet\;C:\Program

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\cas\cas-overlay-template\gradle\tasks.gradle' line: 28

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':run'.
> Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

Answer (score 0):

- CAS 7 needs Java 21 now
- Your issue is that you are running on windows and have to deal with spaces in the path where Java is installed.